# How to run app remotely

Tags: c#, remote-server

I need to run an application remotely so that the application on my other machine so that it creates a folder in its own host. I tried WCF but am not sure it is possible to use it for creating a folder inside the host. 
I appreciate any help and suggestion

Comment: You want to create a new folder on a remote machine? In what context? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you give us some more context on what exactly you are doing?

Comment: thanks for your comments. My plan is to run a program on my pc lets call it pc1 and then it should send request to the second part of the program in another host called pc2. The request should contain a name that the program in pc2 will now create a folder on its own storage with the requested name.